# Remember if I was on the Activity tab when switching between Meta and Main user pages

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks

I often go to a user page to look up some information from the Activity tab, only to realize that I'm looking at Meta when I want to be on Main or vice-versa.

Fortunately, there's a link on the upper-right that I can use to quickly switch between those pages. The problem is that it directs me back to the "Profile" tab every time.

So my workflow becomes:

1. Click username
2. Click "Activity"
3. Oops, wrong site! Click "Meta User" (or "Main User")
4. Oops, wrong tab! Click "Activity" again

**Four clicks, when it could be only three? *For the love of God, Montresor!***

Of course, I could save myself the trouble my performing step 3 before step 2, but I don't always realize it's necessary until after step 2.

When I load the page with `?tab=topactivity`, please add that context to the links that switch between Meta and Main user pages.

Comment: I agree - this is how it should've worked from the start